# Font Awesome icons not working in OSX Safari

Tags: css, macos, twitter-bootstrap, safari, font-awesome

My `font-awesome` icons are working fine in Firefox and Chrome, but in Safari I just see blank space for some of them but not others. Screenshot:

[image: http://imgur.com/8MaOH1I.png]

As you can see, the icons for `fa-twitter`, `fa-instagram` and others just aren't showing up, either on the Font Awesome website or when I try to use them with `<i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>`.

Really bizarre, I've cleared my cache a dozen times and can't figure out what else could be going wrong here.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an old version of Fontawsome installed as a system font? (fontbook) Osx will use your installed font. If that is an old Awesome it will be missing glyphs.

Comment: @Joeri Good idea - I did have Font Awesome installed on OSX, I've deleted it from Font Book and restarted my computer but this hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: Just a suggestion for the future, have you considered this option https://materialdesignicons.com? I know, it's quite late alternative, but I believe it can work too.

Comment: add https:// to sdns .

Answer (score 16):

There may be another issue at play--I was having a similar issue where a custom-generated icon set (using Font Custom) would display in Chrome, Firefox, and some versions of Safari, but no versions of iOS. I made sure I had no popup blockers enabled, but still was experiencing the issue.

Through a bit of research, I found that adding this property to the icon font's CSS fixed the issue:

```
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

After this property was added, rendering in all browsers worked fine.

Comment: can you tell where to add this line?

Comment: worked for me. Add it to @font-face {} in your customicon.css

Comment: Insane! Thanks :)

Comment: Still useful in 2021

Answer (score 13):

Do you have an ad blocker plugin installed in Safari?
According to the Font Awesome documentation, icons of social networks can be blocked with such plugin.

Comment: See here for the still-ongoing discussion: https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/1799

Answer (score 7):

It seems Safari blocks unsigned fonts. Using CDN with integrity resolves the issue:

For font awesome I used below link which I found at: [https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/getting-started?using=web-fonts-with-css](http://font-awesome%20CDN)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: this should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of Chrome? They now have a customized version of web-kit, a branch called Blink so even though they show in Chrome, nowadays, you might need to check in another web-kit browser to be sure.

Also, what the dreaded IE? Do they show there?

I usually have to actually 'Reset Safari' instead of just clearing the cache to actually, clear the cache!

Comment: I've tried in Firefox and Chrome and they work just fine, just not in Safari. Don't have IE to test. I've reset my computer and still no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'FontAwesome'; 
    src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0'); 
    src:url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot #iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'), 
        url('../fonts/fontawesome webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'),
        url('../fonts/fontawesome webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg'); 
    font-weight: normal; 
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had the wrong font family for brand icons.

My old CSS:

```
font-family: "FontAwesome";
```

My new (working) CSS:

```
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Brands";
font-weight: 900;
```

This should help anyone who is using old code & has issues displaying brand icons (Twitter, Facebook etc)

Answer (score 1):

I found that if there is an overriding svg styles of `width: auto; height: auto`, svg (or font awesome icons) will not show in Safari.

Either set a value for width and height or use `width: inherit; height: inherit`

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing your Cache, I have had this happen to me once before and it was fixed after I cleared my Cache (I was using Chrome though).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been years, but to anyone who still deal with this issue, you can just add request params "?v=1234" in the href of <link>

Before:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

After:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css?v=1234" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Credits to @animaster for the answer:
https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/issues/7770#issuecomment-346301072

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding this to css file solved the problem:

```
.fa {
    position: relative;
}
```