# font awesome working only on chrome but not on safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm working on build webpage and not sure why font awesome seems to work on google chrome but not iPhone safari. After deploying my webpage and test it on devices, it didn't work safari. How can I solve this issue?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://static.fontawesome.com/css/fontawesome-app.css">

  <script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/js/all.js"></script>
  

<i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
```

UPDATE:
Here is my attempt using the suggestions yet it doesn't work on safari

```css
i{text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.1/css/all.min.css">

      <script src="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.1/js/all.js"></script>
      

    <i class="fas fa-tasks"></i>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Font Awesome icons not working in OSX Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22751758/font-awesome-icons-not-working-in-osx-safari)

Comment: Hi i have faced the same problem please add in you css  .fa::before {font-family:FontAwesome;}

Comment: @toy moy Use the latest version of CSS cdn link.

Answer (score -1):

Try to add that line into you css for your icon:

text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

Comment: still the same issue occurs

Comment: I added it as i {text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}

Comment: Did you check the possible duplicate? (From xmastertje). It also shows (in the comments below the highest answer) where to put text-rendering. Putting it on `i` is incorrect.